# Get first character of each line from string with multiple lines in Python

Tags: python

I have below string with multiple line:

```
data = """
Come to the
River
Of my
Soulful
Sentiments
Meandering silently
Yearning for release.
Hasten
Earnestly
As my love flows by
Rushing through the flood-gates
To your heart.
"""
```

I want to get a string including the first character of each line in Python.

It should return the result: `'Crossmyheart'`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: first_word_list = []
for line in data.splitlines():
    try:
        first_word_list.append(line.split()[0][0])
    except:
        pass
    
''.join(first_word_list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
data = """
Come to the
River
Of my
Soulful
Sentiments
Meandering silently
Yearning for release.
Hasten
Earnestly
As my love flows by
Rushing through the flood-gates
To your heart.
"""

# Get each line into a list by splitting data on every newline
# ['', 'Come to the', 'River', 'Of my', ... 'To your heart.', '']
data_list = data.split("\n")

# Get a list of the first letter of every list element
# use only those elements with length > 0
# ['C', 'R', 'O', 'S', 'S', 'M', 'Y', 'H', 'E', 'A', 'R', 'T']
letters_list = [x[0] for x in data_list if len(x)>0]

# Join it to make one word
# 'CROSSMYHEART'
my_word = ''.join(letters_list)

# Capitalise only the first letter
my_word = my_word.capitalize()

# Print out the answer. 
# 'Crossmyheart'
print(my_word)
```

Comment: Many thank Pranab, I got the correct result with your code, it is very helpful when I took a lot of time for it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution I could find

```
data = ["Come to the", "River", "Of my", "Soulful", "Sentiments", "Meandering silently", "Yearning for release", "Hasten", "Earnestly", "As my love flows by", "Rushing through the flood-gates", "To your heart"]

newString = ""
for word in data:
    letter = word[0]
    newString = newString + letter
    print(newString[-1], end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to split your data into a list, then select lines that are not empty, append the first character of the string to a list and finally join the list to form a string.

It can be achieved in a single python line

```
x = ''.join([i[0] for i in data.splitlines() if len(i) > 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could leverage the built in regex lib found in python as the first letter of each line contains a capital letter.

```py
>>> import re
>>> def get_first_letter(data):
...     # Extracts the first capital letter in each line
...     first_letter_each_line = re.findall(r'[A-Z]', data)
...     # Concatenates it
...     concat = ''.join(first_letter_each_line)
...     # Formats string
...     return concat.capitalize()
>>> get_first_letter(data)
'Crossmyheart'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = """
Come to the
River
Of my
Soulful
Sentiments
Meandering silently
Yearning for release.
Hasten
Earnestly
As my love flows by
Rushing through the flood-gates
To your heart.
"""

text = data[1];
i = 1
while i < len(data):
  if i+1 == len(data):
    break;
  if data[i] == '\n':
    text = text + data[i+1].lower()
  i = i + 1
print(text)
```

First, I get the first character of string which easiest to find and already in capital letter.

For other character, I just used loop to checked for the new line `'\n'` character to get the next character after `'\n'` (it's the first character of line) then lower it and the concat them together. The loop will break if the next character is last character.

len() is function for find the length of string.

lower() is function for lower character/string.

Hope this might can help you ^^